# Custom PCB based on LM2596SX-3.3 shorting out

Tags: pcb-design, buck

I designed a custom pcb based on this https://github.com/azrael783/esphome_garagedoor_opener and this https://github.com/jampez77/garage_door_sensor for esphome/homeassistant
I nailed the esp part but the power supply is not working.

For context the controller for the garage door have 2 buttons for up and down that you can connect to and a output that give 24v dc and a analog signal with the door status.

I designed my power supply around a LM2596SX-3.3 that should give 3.3v to my esp from the 24v of the controller board
I followed the typical application in the datasheet but i had to replace a couple of components, for example i used a SS54 smd diode instead of the 1N5824

I attached the schematic and the pcb layout

For what happens: when i connect a 24dc power supply to the input it shorts or at least seems like it. What can I do to troubleshoot the problem?

I forgot a capacitor on the input, I don't have one for 24v on hand atm but is this the issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: C3 is 220uF? Doubt. How about  a datasheet link on that one.

Comment: Sure, here is C3: https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/_Murata-Electronics-_C412252.html
I bought almost everything on LCSC

Comment: Mounted one of the diodes backwards?

Comment: To elaborate on my previous comment, D4 seems to be drawn backwards on the PCB, compared to the schematic. (the schematic looks right, not the PCB).

Comment: I checked but: D3 have the stripe on the up side of the PCB image (Net D3 A) i attached and D5 on the down side (GND), they should be ok. I can provide a photo of the pcb if helps D4 has the stripe exacly where you see it on the pcb, isnt the stripe the negative side?

Comment: @Exico That's impressive. It will typically be about 78uF at 3.3V bias and room temperature, but still quite impressive for the size.

Comment: also check if you have no solder bridge between pins (3 and 4) and (4 and 5) of IC4 (they are rather close). And if you have a multi-meter, check if in power off state you have a short between GND and 24V or GND and 3.3V. A photo of the PCB might be a good idea.

Comment: @Exico The stripe on the diode is the same as the stripe on the schematic symbol, i.e. the cathode. Should be pointed towards +24V. Right now, if Q1 starts conducting (which it will if nothing is connected to SommerSIG since there is no pull-down on the gate) you basically have a short circuit.

Comment: No shorts, I added a photo. @Klas-Kenny I replicated the original pcb with that design, maybe when i connect it to the control board it will work but I wanted to test it before that. Im gonna check the original design

Comment: @Exico With D4 mounted as it is now, turning on Q1 will always produce a short circuit. No matter if connected to anything else or not. If SommerSIG was connected to 0V you wouldn't see a short right away, but when the signal goes high.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny I attached the original design and from what i see i inverted the diode, note that the photo is taken from the bottom of the board, my pcb is from the top. My mistake then, I should fix it in schematics and PCB layout. For now a inversion should do the trick

Comment: Unfortunately its still shorting but now the LM2596SX is heating up. I inverted D5 too, I guess that I should mark better on the silkscreen the polarity. Thank you all for the help.
TLDR: D4 was inverted in schematics and D5 was inverted on placement by error

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the quick help.

- D4 was inverted in schematics and silkscreen on PCB
- D5 was inverted when I placed it, was fine on schematics and PCB

I will publish this project on github when is ready under the name SommerESP. In the meantime thank you again